# Posting a tweet to a Twitter account using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, winforms, twitter, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to look for an example of how to simply post a tweet on my Twitter account using C# and DotNetOpenAuth. I want to do it from a WinForms application. The examples I found seem to be using ASP.NET and WebForms. Specifically, i'm getting hung up on the "verifier code". Here is the code I have so far:

```
private McMurryTokenManager TokenManager
{
    get
    {
        McMurryTokenManager tokenManager = null;

        string consumerKey = ConsumerKey;
        string consumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey))
        {
            tokenManager = new McMurryTokenManager 
                { ConsumerKey = consumerKey, ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret };
        }

        return tokenManager;
    }
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var twitter = new DesktopConsumer(TwitterConsumer.ServiceDescription, TokenManager);
    string requestToken;
    twitter.RequestUserAuthorization(null, null, out requestToken);
    var accessTokenResponse = twitter.ProcessUserAuthorization(requestToken, null);
}
```

I'm getting an error saying the verifier code can't be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. The RequestUserAuthorization method returns a URL to an authorization page.
2. You should redirect the user to that page, typically Process.Start(url), where the user will authorize your application.
3. Twitter the redirects the user to a page with a multi-digit number, which is the verifier.
4. After you've sent the user to the authorization page, your application should wait with a dialog or prompt so that the user can enter the verifier and submit it to your application.
5. Once you have the verifier, pass it as the 2nd argument to ProcessUserAuthorization.

Here's a blog post that say's something similar and has a code example:

http://whelkaholism.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-doing-stuff-with-google-using-oauth.html